# Disk utility unable to change partition type

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, sd-card

I'm trying to copy a `.img` disk image to a microSD. However, when I try to move the contents of the image I downloaded to the microSD, I get this:

[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

Same result when copying via Terminal.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ luke$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD-256                 255.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.9 GB     disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 EV3_BOOT                50.3 MB    disk1s1
   2:                      Linux                         1.8 GB     disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.9 GB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 NO NAME                 7.9 GB     disk2s1
```

When using this:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ev3-ev3dev-jessie-2015-07-08.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=4m
```

I get this:

```
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Permission denied
```

But when using this:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ev3-ev3dev-jessie-2015-07-08.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=4m
```

I get this:

```
dd: /dev/rdisk1: Resource busy
```

Both approaches asked for, and accepted, my administrator password.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock switch on the card was not locked, but after locking and unlocking it (turning it off and back on) again, it worked fine.

Problem solved.